# R: Including help of a function into Quarto document

Tags: r, function, knitr, quarto

The following [r](/questions/tagged/r) code gives the output

```
example(
    topic          = mean
  , package        = "base"
  , type           = "html"
  )
```

[image]

Wondering how to add similar kind colored output in [quarto](/questions/tagged/quarto) document.

My attempt and its output is below:

````
---
title: "Help"
format: html
---


```{r}
#| echo: false
example(
    topic          = mean
  , package        = "base"
  , type           = "html"
  )
```
````

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get syntax highlighting, you may use `class-output: r`,

````
---
title: "Help"
format: html
---


```{r}
#| echo: false
#| class-output: r

example(
    topic          = mean
  , package        = "base"
  , type           = "html"
  )
```
````

---

[image: colored help output]